# How to create a tab control in iOS similar to Windows Forms?

Tags: ios, tabcontrol

I am looking to create a tabcontrol similar to the one present in Windows Forms.

Here is an image of what I am looking to achieve:
[image]

What I have in mind to creating this is having buttons at the top and clicking those buttons would hide or show Views depending on which button is clicked.

Is there an easier way to create this component or is this the only way?

Comment: This question is not valid for SO and is to broad. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either a UITabBarController (Bottom) or you can use a UISegmentedControl. And handle each time you select a UISegmentedControl item, you change a ContainerView (Which will act as the pin/window).

Of course, you will have to play with .isHidden true and false.

Another option is, instead of using a Container View, using a horizontal Collection View with scrolling disabled. And when you select a UISegmentedControlItem, you scroll programmatically to the other item. Each CollectionView item would act as the pin/windows.

If you are not comfortable with any of these options, you can look for a third-party library. For example https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

Answer (score 0):

Look up the `UITabBarController`. It sounds like a fit for the job.